# How to pass dropdown/select values to the form's action part in django?

Tags: python, django

I've a simple form with a dropdown menu on my index page. I want the user to be redirected based on the value he/she selects from the drop down.

As a workaround I collected the dropdown value in the views, while my index page form redirects them to an intermediate page. After it goes through the intermediate page, the next page would be displayed based on the selected value from the form.

But I would like to have a more dynamic approach to it, where the action part of the index form could catch the dropdown value.

```
{% extends 'raffle_form/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form role="form" action="{% url '<choice value to be dynamically appear here!>' %}" method="post" validate>
    {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-12" align="center">Select Your Choice!</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="choice" size="0" style="border-radius: 35px;">
                            <option value="choice1">CHOICE 1</option>
                            <option value="choice2">CHOICE 2</option>
                            <option value="choice3">CHOICE 3</option>
                        </select>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Proceed</button>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </form>
{% endblock%}
```

Any suggestions/guidelines would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does it need to be a form? Can't you just have each item in the dropdown as an `<a href='something_here'>CHOICE Name</a>`?

Comment: I need the values later as well. But I could give a try to this suggestion. Its simple and probably it would work.

I'll let you if it worked for me.

Thanks mate.